# Dynamic buffer to save pressed keys - c++

Tags: c++, buffer, keylogger

im building a security implemention for a company, need to capture all the keys pressed in a specific window and save them in a buffer to dump them in a file every 5 minutes.

Then, every 7 minutes the log is sent by mail and the file is deleted. Is it a good choice to do this? Is there a better option?

The buffer is to prevent the file from being used when erasing it.

The problem that is presented to me is, what kind of buffer should I use for this purpose? It must be dynamic since I do not know how many keys will be pressed before the file is saved.

Or is there any way to dump a static buffer into a file every time it gets full?

Comment: there are already products that do that.

Answer (score 1):

Simple [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would be ok for this purpose, as it grows automatically and its growth strategy would handle well your scenario. You may as well use [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) but saving vector to a file might be easier.
For each keypress I'd store some struct to hold info about keypress event. If yoy are on windows it might make sense to simply store lParam and wParam of each [keyboard message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) that you handle. You need wParam to store that extra info that comes with each key, like Ctrl+Alt when a key was pressed.
For example:

```
#include <windows.h>

struct keypress
{
    UINT lParam; // The character code of the key. 
    UINT wParam; // The repeat count, scan code, extended-key flag etc.
};
typedef std::vector<keypress> keystore;
```

You may as well use string, but it'd rather not to, there is need for strings here. If you simply case for simple text input, you may possibly be ok even with something simple as `typedef std::vector<char> keystore;`

Comment: And what datatype should I use? I need save keys, date and some text (log)